# Reactjs Script Server not available

Tags: reactjs, server, react-scripts

"React-scripts", a series of scripts from create-react-app starter pack allows me to use "react-scripts-start" to initialize a server. 
Everything works fine, the server turns on and I can access it on localhost:3000 or by using the IP:3000
The problem is when I use other devices from my house. I try to connect to the IP:3000 and it doesn't work. I'm getting "Server not found". 
Is it a Windows access problem or am I supposed to set up the server?

Comment: Are these devices in the same network?

Comment: Yes they are. Both smartphone and another laptop are connected to the same router as the server hosting laptop

Comment: I would try opening a port and try connecting to it to see if the problem is something related to react-scripts or not. eg: Server: `nc -l -p 3000`. Client: `nc server-ip 3000`

Comment: You need to open port 3000 on the Windows Firewall. For Windows 10: https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-open-firewall-ports-in-windows-10,36451.html

Comment: I opened port 3000, I also tried connecting to that port using Test-NetConnection IP -Port 3000 and it works. Unfortunately, server is still not available on other devices. I'm not sure if I have to do anything with routing within the router

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my issue. For me, it was not in the firewall, not in the configuration files. Instead, it was the router. 
Since I live in UK, I have Hub 3.0 from Virgin Media.
The solution is:

1) Navigate to Connected Devices and copy the IP address for your device. In my case it was xx.xx.0.16/24 so I copied "xx.xx.0.16"

2) Navigate to Advanced Settings > Security > Port Forwarding

3) Click on "Create new Rule". For Local IP will be your IP address, local start port & end port 3000; external start port & end port 3000; Protocol choose both; Enabled on

4) Apply changes

Now here is the trick. When I run the command

> npm run start

I'm getting a message which says:

You ca now view your project in the browser:

Local:            http://localhost:3000/

On Your Network:  http://xx.xx.37.1:3000/

I can navigate to that IP address : 3000 on the hosting laptop however if I want to make other devices access it, I must use the IP address set up in the router which for me is xx.xx.0.16:3000